# When BufferedReader.read(char[]) returns -1?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, sdk, bufferedreader

I'm working with an Evolis card Printer SDK, it communicates with client using JsonRPC through a TCP socket.

I have a Java example provided by the manufacturer, but I have some trouble with the socket read:

```
package MinimalClient;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MinimalClient 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try {
                String ip = "11.1.24.210";
                int port = 18000;
                char[] data = new char[1024];
                String request = "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":\"1\",\"method\":\"CMD.SendCommand\",\"params\":{\"command\":\"Rfv\", \"device\":\"Evolis Primacy\", \"timeout\":\"5000\"}}"; 
                String answer = "";

                Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                byte[] byteRequest = request.getBytes("UTF-8");

                out.write(byteRequest);

                out.flush();

                while( (br.read(data)) != -1 ) 
                {
                    answer = new String(data);
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }

                socket.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            { 
                System.out.println("Communication failed :\n");
                System.out.println(" - check TCP communication is activated\n");
                System.out.println(" - check the service is activated\n");
                System.out.println(" - check your IP address and port\n");                          
            }
    }
}
```

I'm stuck in the `while( (br.read(data)) != -1 )` because after the first loop, BufferedReader.read doesn't return -1 and stays there until the timeout!

The first run gets all JSON of the reply content and then the second run is stuck because there is nothing to read.

When BufferedReader.read(char[]) returns -1?

Answer (score 0):

When the sender on the other end of the buffer completes sending the stream of data, would the 'read' method return -1. Usually reading from persistent store like a disk, when the last char is read from the file from the disk the method returns -1.

However, this is a 'Socket', and the 'sender' is on the other side of the network. I would suspect that the 'sender' should flush() and close() their side of 'output stream' for your 'read()' method to get a -1.

You should get in touch with your vender and check this out. All the best, and hope this helped.

Comment: You are almost correct in your answer. If you are interested, read my answer about the condition where your reader gets to the end of a file that is open elsewhere for writing

Comment: Yes, and that's why I think the sender is still holding the stream open and never closed it which makes this br.read() think that the sender is still going to send something only for it to time out. Are you suggesting that there are two writers to the same 'output stream' on the 'sender' side, where the first guy would have 'closed' but not the second? Interesting, but not sure if two guys can 'write' to the same 'output stream'. Never tried that.

Comment: In this case the sender (server) should not close the connection as this is a connection between printer and client and there can be some more exchanges before che connection closing. I cannot understand theoretically a client TCP connection should stop reading for common protocols: HTTP (with keepalive), maybe it usees the message length declared at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader.read(char[]) will return -1 for a file if (a) you've reached the end of the file and (b) the file is open for writing somewhere else. Otherwise, it will wait for more data to be written to the stream.

The way to fix this is to check that the entire JsonRPC message has been sent, and close the connection on your side

```
            while( (br.read(data)) != -1 ) 
            {
                answer = new String(data);
                System.out.println(answer);
                if (testForCompleteness(answer)) socket.close();
            }
```

Comment: I mean, then the stream readers would also have to be closed though with this approach. I mean the InputStreamReader and the BufferedReader. I think this is one way to solve it though, but we still would not know why the sender in this case did not confirm that the sending infact completed.

Comment: The question is regarding the stream, not regarding the json.

Comment: @Siva once you close the socket, the InputStreamReader and BufferedReader will be automatically closed as well.

Comment: @Silva I can't tell you for 100% certainty why the sender did not close the socket on their side. But I think it's quite likely that they are still listening for new messages from your side, to which they would respond. You might want to try using a threaded callback listener like DataFetcher (http://tus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tus/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java?view=log)(which I wrote years ago for doing communication over sockets)

Comment: The sender leaves the socket open, but closes the output stream I thought?

Comment: @Siva Closing either stream closes the whole Socket. You can test this yourself by making a ServerSocket, connecting to it, and closing one of the Server-side socket's streams.

Comment: What is `answer.testForCompleteness()` in String class?